# Maximum consecutive months of netflix subscription for every customer

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with two columns Name, and Date which has the details about customers who buy Netflix subscriptions on monthly basis.

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Ram | 2021-01-01 |
| Ram | 2021-02-01 |
| Sam | 2021-01-01 |
| Sam | 2021-02-01 |
| Sam | 2021-03-01 |
| Ram | 2021-06-01 |
| Ram | 2021-07-01 |
| Ram | 2021-08-01 |
| Sam | 2021-08-01 |
| Sam | 2021-09-01 |
| Sam | 2021-10-01 |
| Sam | 2021-11-01 |

I want to get the maximum consecutive months of subscription for every customer.

For the above data, The output should look like this:

| Name | start_month | end_month | max_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ram | 2021-06-01 | 2021-08-01 | 3 |
| Sam | 2021-08-01 | 2021-11-01 | 4 |

can anyone help me with how to do this query using MySQL?

Table creation code:

```sql
Create table If Not Exists Netflix (Name varchar(10), Date Date);

insert into Netflix (Name, Date) values ('Ram', '2021-01-01');
insert into Netflix (Name, Date) values ('Ram', '2021-02-01');
insert into Netflix (Name, Date) values ('Sam', '2021-01-01');
insert into Netflix (Name, Date) values ('Sam', '2021-02-01');
insert into Netflix (Name, Date) values ('Sam', '2021-03-01');
insert into Netflix (Name, Date) values ('Ram', '2021-06-01');
insert into Netflix (Name, Date) values ('Ram', '2021-07-01');
insert into Netflix (Name, Date) values ('Ram', '2021-08-01');
insert into Netflix (Name, Date) values ('Sam', '2021-08-01');
insert into Netflix (Name, Date) values ('Sam', '2021-09-01');
insert into Netflix (Name, Date) values ('Sam', '2021-10-01');
insert into Netflix (Name, Date) values ('Sam', '2021-11-01');
```

Comment: use `GROUP BY Name`, and in your `SELECT` you would use an aggregate function, in this case `COUNT(*) AS max_count`. For start/end dates, you can use `MIN(Date)` and `MAX(Date)`.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Note: It's probably better to use `VARCHAR(255)` than some ridiculously tiny `VARCHAR(10)` that's likely to lead to all kinds of silent truncation issues.

Comment: @Asgar, it 8.0.28

Comment: @Rogue, I think your logic will give the total months of subscription taken along with start and end. But I will not give the consecutive months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. But didn't include the start and end months here.

```sql
with cte as (select *, date_sub(Date, interval rn month) as diff
from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by Name order by Date) as rn from netflix
)a)
select Name, max(x) from (select Name,count(rn) over(partition by Name,diff) as x
  from cte)a group by Name;
```